# Mongoengine: create a QuerySet from a MongoDB cursor

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

Some part of the application I'm working in is expecting a mongoengine QuerySet.

I have a MongoDB cursor with the info I need, generated by an aggregation.

Since mongoengine documentation specifies that a QuerySet is a wrapper of a MongoDB cursor, **is there any way to create a QuerySet with a given cursor?**

**Note:** There is an obvious solution, querying the database again:

`queryset = Model.objects.filter(_id__in=[r['_id'] for r in cursor])`

But it's rather ugly. The ideal solution would be something like calling the constructor of QuerySet, since it is a wrapper of cursor. But constructor does not accept cursor as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

QuerySet is nothing but just a list. So you can convert the output you get from aggregating into a list like below and directly use that list as QuerySet.

```
queryset = list(cursor)
```